# Typehinting lambda function as function argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a function that takes in a lambda:

```
def my_function(some_lambda):
  # do stuff
  some_other_variable = some_lambda(some_variable)

my_function(lambda x: x + 2)
```

I would like to typehint the lambda function passed.

I've tried

```
def my_function(some_lambda: lambda) -> None:
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
from typing import Lambda
# ImportError: cannot import name 'Lambda'
```

My IDE complains about similar things on 2.7 straddled typehints, eg

```
def my_function(some_lambda: lambda) -> None:
  # type: (lambda) -> None
# formal parameter name expected
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is obvious when you think about it, but it took a while to register in the head. A lambda is a function. There is no function type but there is a `Callable` type in the `typing` package. The solution to this problem is

```
from typing import Callable
def my_function(some_lambda: Callable) -> None:
```

Python 2 version:

```
from typing import Callable
def my_function(some_lambda):
  # type: (Callable) -> None
```

Comment: You can also further restrict the function type: e.g., `Callable[[int], int]` is the type of a one-argument function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

[Callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable) is the answer to your question.

```
from typing import Callable


some_lambda: Callable[[int] int] = lambda x: x + 2


def my_function(func: Callable[[int], int]) -> None:
    # do some stuff
        

my_function(some_lambda)
```